# Vectorize a double loop in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, vectorization

How do I vectorize the following in [MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB)?

```
n=1000;
m=n;
for i=1:n
    T(i,i)=i.^2;
    for j=1:m
        x(i,j)=2*((i+j)^(-2)-(i-j)^(-2))/pi;
    end
    x(i,i)=0;
end

for i=1:n
    for j=1:m
        if mod(i,2)==mod(j,2)
            x(i,j)=0;
        end

    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `T`:

```
T = diag((1:n).^2);
```

For `x`:

```
[ii jj] = meshgrid(1:n,1:m);
x = 2*((ii+jj).^(-2)-(ii-jj).^(-2))/pi;
x(mod(ii,2)==mod(jj,2))=0;
```

Comment: Why is this answer suddenly so helpful?

Comment: sorry for the belated response (i did upvoted it but only now accept it) this helps vectorized a basis set of "particle in a box" eigen functions, a simple "sines" type basis set that is useful in physics and chemistry. I don't know why ot was suddently so helpful, maybe other people were looking for it at the same time...